# How to use regular expressions to extract the term inbetween the square brackets in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have something like:

$string1="dog fox [cat]"

I need the contents inside [ ] i.e cat

another question: if you are familiar with regex in one language, will it do for the other languages as well?

Comment: Just a note, however, you can only accept one answer for each question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
$matchcount = preg_match('/\[([^\]]*)\]/', $string1, $matches);
$item_inside_brackets = $matches[1];
```

If you want to match multiple bracketed terms in the same string, you'll want to look into `preg_match_all` instead of just `preg_match`.

And yes, regular expressions are a fairly cross-language standard (there are some variations in what features are available in different languages, and occasional syntax differences, but for the most part it's all the same).

Explanation of the above regex:

```
/            # beginning of regex delimiter
\[           # literal left bracket (normally [ is a special character)
(            # start capture group - isolate the text we actually want to extract
[^\]]*       # match any number of non-] characters
)            # end capture group
\]           # literal right bracket
/            # end of regex delimiter
```

The contents of the `$matches` array are set based on both the entirety of the text matched (which would include the brackets) in [0], and then the contents of each capture group from the matching in [1] and up (first capture group's contents in [1], second in [2], etc).

Comment: Don’t use the non-greedy quantifier when you can use a negated character class. `/\[([^\]]*)\]/` is a better regular expression for this case.

Comment: Quite surprised he didn't pick yours, +1 from me though

Comment: It is working pretty well. But I am getting undefined offset error for strings that don't have [ ] 

How to eliminate the offset?

Comment: Check the the count of matches is greater than 0.

if(count($matches) > 0) {
}

Comment: Or just check the return value from `preg_match`, which my example code above already stores in `$matchcount`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the php code:

```
preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', $string1, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

And yes, your knowledge will transfer. Although there my be subtle differences between each language's version of regular expressions.